# dependent observations for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I am trying to set up a logistic regression model for inventory units and sales.

My binary response variable (sales) is 1 if overall sales are up over last year and 0 if they are not.
I have about 30 independent variables which are a count of inventory units by category (30 categories).
The goal is to rank categories based on how influential their inventory levels are to whether sales are up.

My data is set up as follows with about 300 rows:

Week    Cat1.      Cat2.   Cat3.    Cat4.  ...   Catn  Sales

My problem is that inventory in week 2 is dependent on inventory in week 1 and so on, so I fail the independence assumption.
How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: To which "independence assumption" are you referring to? In a regression problem we only have to make sure regressors are not collinear.

Comment: My understanding is that there are several assumptions with logistic regression - independence of observations being one of them.

Comment: @GregBrown Do you believe the inventory in week 3 to depend on the inventory in week 1 beyond the fact that week 1 inventory influences week 2 inventory (which influences week 3 inventory)? That is, if you know the week 2 inventory, would you expect it to help you to know the week 1 inventory as well? (I’m thinking of something called a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).)

Comment: @Dave, no the inventory levels are dependent to the level you describe - I cannot know week 1 levels given week 2 values - nor does week one influence week 3 beyond the transitory property.